# display jQuery prettyPhoto lightbox in parent window from iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, parent

I know this issue has been discussed before but I can't seem to get it to work. I have a master HTML page with an iframe. I am using jQuery prettyphoto and I was wondering how I can get the light box to display in the parent window when I click on the link in the iframe?

**Master Page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Master Page</title>
</head>

<body>
 <iframe src="iframe.html" width="300" height="300px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**iFrame Page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>iframe</title>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
 @import url("assets/css/infotech-iframes.css");
 @import url("assets/css/infotech-popup.css");
</style>

<script src="assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.popup.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <a href="assets/images/screenshots/campaign-setup-lg.png" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"><img src="assets/images/screenshots/campaign-setup-sm.gif" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
 });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 2):

CalebD's answer is correct (please see the post for more details). However in order to have access to the API in the parent of the iFrame you must add the following initialization code in the parent, in order for any of this to work

```
$.fn.prettyPhoto({ social_tools: false });
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if the domain for the parent and child frames are the same.

You'll need to load the necessary JavaScript in the parent frame. Then try something like this in the iframe:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        window.parent.$.prettyPhoto.open($(this).attr('src'), $(this).attr('title'), $(this).children('img').attr('alt'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

You might have to change the `$('a')` selector to something else. I don't think you should put `rel` on the links because you might get pretty photo opening in both the parent and the iframe.

This should all work in theory. I have not tested it.

Comment: Hi,

I tried your suggestion but still get the same result of the lightbox displaying within the iframe instead of the parent page. Would you have anu further suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Were there any JavaScript errors? Did you remove the rel attribute from the <a> tags? Does pretty photo work from the parent frame if you call it manually as a test? Are you using the most recent version of pretty photo?